# SQL Server : OUTER JOIN with GROUP BY clause doesn't return all possible combinations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, outer-join

I am querying two tables:

1. `tblPurhcaseOrders` - holds purchase orders with various columns, one of which is a foreign key called `OrderTypeID`
2. `tblOrderTypes` - holds 4 types of purchase orders

One of the order types in `tblOrderTypes` was added later than the first 3 basic ones. Thus,  instances of purchase orders with this newer order type appear only from a certain point of time (Feb. 2012).

I'm writing an aggregated query which should ultimately bring me the sum of all purchase orders, grouped by their type.

I do want the results to me 0 or NULL, even if I query a point of time in which the newer order type had not existed yet.

Here's how my query looks like:

```
SELECT
   MONTH(tblPurchaseOrders.DeliveryDate) AS sMonth,
   YEAR(tblPurchaseOrders.DeliveryDate) AS sYear, 
   tblOrderType.OrderTypeName,
   SUM(ISNULL(TotalPrice,0)) AS sValue 
FROM        
   tblPurchaseOrders 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
   tblOrderTypes ON tblPurchaseOrders.OrderTypeID = tblOrderTypes.OrderTypeID  
WHERE       
   MONTH(DeliveryDate) = 1  
   AND YEAR(DeliveryDate) = 2012
GROUP BY
   MONTH(DeliveryDate), YEAR(DeliveryDate), tblOrderType.OrderTypeName
```

Now, the query above works just fine and provides me with correct aggregation, only it leaves out the newer order type (reminder, it didn't exist in JAN-2012 yet).

If I change the query condition to `MONTH(DeliveryDate) = 2 AND YEAR(DeliveryDate) = 2012` it appears.

I've tried full join and also tried switching between the order of the two tables and toggled to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
WHERE       
   MONTH(DeliveryDate) = 1  
   AND YEAR(DeliveryDate) = 2012
```

into

```
AND
   MONTH(DeliveryDate) = 1  
   AND YEAR(DeliveryDate) = 2012
```

Comment: Your suggested solution works perfectly when I shift the conditions to the JOIN clause. Thank you @Madhivanan.